# Quelle autre formulation pourrait exprimer la même idée que "Tu crois détenir la vérité absolue en matière de mode?"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation

Au sens où ladite personne a une confiance absolue dans son jugement esthétique, elle sait ce qui est beau et ce qui ne l'est pas, ce qui est au goût du jour, sans laisser aucune place à la discussion, en d'autres mots son jugement est sans appel, elle a toujours raison.

Comment: < — Ah ! Le juge de Paix vient de parler, on n'a plus qu'à se taire et se rhabiller selon ses critères. » … et attendre la réaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quelques possibilités*

- Penses-tu avoir le dernier mot en matière de mode ?
- Tu te crois la référence universelle en matière de mode ?
- Alors tu t'imagines savoir ce que la mode devrait et ne devrait pas être ?
- Il faut donc que ta conception de la mode soit celle de tout le monde ?
- Tu ne penses pas que quelqu'un pourrait penser de la mode autre chose que toi ?

Answer (score 2):

Pour compléter la réponse de LPH,

On a souvent tendance à utiliser l'expression "*science infuse*" lorsque l'on reproche à quelqu'un d'être trop sûr de son propre avis (mais probablement généralement dans des sujets plus objectifs que la mode).

Ainsi, pour avoir une phrase sarcastique qui reste assez percutante :

> Tu penses avoir la science infuse de la mode ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que « science de la mode infuse » ait une signification bien définie. « mode infuse » doit aller, mais la mode n'est pas une science. Quelque chose comme « Tu penses que ton sens de la mode découle de la mode infuse ? » ou « Tu penses avoir le don de la mode infuse ? » pourrait convenir. Vérifier « https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/infuse » et « https://www.google.com/search?q=%22infuse%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr ».

Comment: « Science » en tant que terme signifiant « savoir » est un terme vieilli.

Comment: @LPH C'est aussi le propre du sarcasme de construire du nouveau, le plus souvent éphémère, en variant à l'infini sur des morceaux connus. On ne touche pas là au summum de l'élégance recherchée, de l'exactitude pointilleuse et de la confirmité exacte à la langue consignée dans les écrits du passé. On cherche plutôt un effet instantané. En cela, on pourrait considérer la réplique proposée comme acceptable. Sa force de frappe ne serait peut-être pas optimale, mais ça pourrait passer.

Comment: « Tu penses avoir la ***science infuse** de la mode* ? » en retour d'une réflexion issue d'un ego boursouflé.

Comment: Je suis de l'avis de user Personne, il vaut mieux s'en tenir à l'expression figée.

Comment: @Personne ...ou quelque variation sur votre autre proposition: «Tiens! La science infuse département mode qui éclaire l'abîme de notre ignorance!» Ça se décline de bien des manières...

Comment: @Pasunclue — Pour une réflexion plus incisive avec l'intonation ‘bienveillamment vacharde’ (sourire ironique inclus) : « Tiens ! Voilà la science infuse spécialisé dans la mode … »

Comment: @LPH — À l'autre extrémité du lien "cntrl.fr…", *infuse* est rattaché à *science* et non à l'objet de la science dans l'expression consacrée.

Comment: @Personne Ce qui rend cette expression un problème c'est que d'un côté sans la combinaison avec le verbe « avoir » on doit comprendre « science infuse » comme signifiant « Science qu'Adam a reçue de Dieu » et d'un autre, justement lorsque le verbe « avoir » est utilisé en combinaison, « un savoir sans avoir fait d'efforts pour l'acquérir ». Ce sont deux choses différentes.

Comment: @LPH — Moult Français ignorent l'origine de l'expression *science infuse* mais en connaissent aussi bien le sens que ceux de *science* et de *infuse*. Entendre *mode infuse* fait penser à une tisane (*mode infusée*), *science* et *infuse* sont inséparables du fait de l'usage accepté par tous.

Comment: @Personne Je vois, on ne peut pas appliquer la définition « Au fig. [En parlant de choses intellectuelles et morales, de qualités, de sentiments] Que l'on possède naturellement, qui sont répandues dans. Force, pensée, simplicité infuse. » ; la mode n'est pas une force, une qualité ni un sentiment. « Don infus  de la mode » serait conforme cependant.

Comment: @LPH On doit comprendre l'intention de la personne qui parle, pas l'intention déduite par l'analyse (antérieure ou subséquente) d'un dictionnaire. Si on ne comprend pas, demander à la personne est plus sûr que de demander au dictionnaire. La personne, par exemple, pourrait avoir des lacunes dans sa connaissance d'un mot ou d'une expression, ou alors l'expression pourrait exister depuis peu et n'être pas encore entérinée, ou être détournée de sa signification par amusement (ou par sarcasme). Interpréter ses dires par dictionnaire interposé risquerait d'aboutir à une fausse conclusion.

Comment: @LPH — « Don infus de la mode » est tout à fait audible. Le français vit dans l'oralité (avec les messages sensibles qui ne sont pas des mots) et se codifie dans l'écrit, qui est lié aux concepts limités par l'ambivalence de la lecture des mots.

Comment: @Personne Votre dernier message est vraiment bien. J'ai de la difficulté à comprendre ce qui a porté vos pensées dans cette direction, mais c'est rudement bien observé et joliment exprimé.

Comment: @Pasunclue … seulement un retour à la source des langues indo-européennes.